# XSLT to test a condition for all children without using foreach

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xslt, xpath

I have an XML

```
<Students>
  <Student id ="Stu1" />
  <Student id ="Stu2" />
  <Student id ="Stu3" />
</Students>
```

I am trying to transform it using XSLT.

I need to choose a Students element only if one of its children has id containing "2".

i used the following XSLT

```
<xsl:if test="contains(Student/@id, '2')">
</xsl:if>
```

This works fine if the Stu2 is present in the first child element. But not otherwise.

Is there any way to test the condition for all children **without using foreach**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to choose a Students element only if one of its children has id
>   containing "2".

It's not clear in what context you need to "choose" it - but you could use:

```
 ...select="Students[Student[contains(@id, '2')]]"
```

to select (or match) **all** such Students elements.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This has bugged me a lot all day yesterday!

Answer (score 1):

Use the contains in a predicate e.g. `<xsl:if test="Student[contains(@id, '2')]">...</xsl:if>`.